# Dr. StrangeNumbers or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Floating Point Arithmetic

Tags: programming, numerics, machine-precision, faq

The following is the program.

```
test[t_, dt_] := 
 Module[{}, For[ti = dt, ti <= t, ti = ti + dt, Print[ti];]; 
  Print[MemberQ[{0.01, 0.02}, ti]]; Return[0];]    
test[0.01, 0.001]

(* 0.001
...
False
0 *)
```

Obviously the result is wrong. Copy the above result, you will be surprised to see:

```
(* ...
0.009000000000000001`
0.010000000000000002`
... *)
```

Why is this so?

Comment: This is not a Mathematica question - it is a numerical analysis question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

Comment: It's not the `For[]` loop, really. Try `0.008 + 0.001 // InputForm`. Welcome to the fun of floating-point arithmetic!

Comment: Good,Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of `Module[{}, ...]` with empty variable list? As far as I understand, it should not have any effect at all.

Comment: @celtschk I've used it a few times as a cool parentheses, reserved for future use... Then I stopped doing that

Comment: @Guesswho I see that you added the `faq` tag.  I've typically been using it only when [there are a minimum of eight duplicates.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1526/121)  This question presently has only two.  Maybe you can find others that should be marked as duplicates?  (Possibly questions that have been deleted that should have been marked duplicate instead?)

Comment: I'll try to look for some, @Mr. Wizard; I believe this has been asked here in one form or another (which also makes searching difficult).

Answer (score 17):

While it is a bad idea to compare floating point numbers, in this case I think something simpler is going on: you have an off-by-1 problem in your loop. See what your code does:

```
test[t_, dt_] := Module[{},
  For[ti = dt, ti <= t, ti = ti + dt, Print[ti];];
  Print[MemberQ[{0.01, 0.02}, ti]];
  Return[0];
  ]
```

then, after

```
test[0.01, .001];
```

look at `ti`:

```
ti
(*0.011*)
```

If you use `<` rather than `<=` in the condition, the final value will indeed be 
what you expect it to be:

```
test2[t_, dt_] := Module[{},
  For[ti = dt, ti < t, ti = ti + dt, Print[ti];];
  Print[MemberQ[{0.01, 0.02}, ti]];
  Return[0];
  ]

test2[0.01, .001]
ti
```

prints a list up to `0.009` and returns `True`.

In general, though, don't do things like that with floating-point numbers. Even if it works here, it will eventually fail. Observe:

```
(1 + $MaxMachineNumber) == $MaxMachineNumber
(*True*)
```

or, as JM points out,

```
1 + $MachineEpsilon == 1
(*True*)
```

Comment: The more traditional example is `1 + $MachineEpsilon == 1`... ;)

Comment: @J.M. Tradition is for wimps :)

Comment: Bear in mind `Equal` applies an extra tolerance in *Mathematica*. The proper comparison is ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = -Infinity}, 
 1 == 1 + $MachineEpsilon]`` (= `False`) vs. ``Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = -Infinity}, 
 1 == 1 + $MachineEpsilon/2]`` (= `True`).

Comment: @OleksandrR. I didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work fine and is more in the spirit of the Mathematica way and perhaps illustrates why a Functional approach tends to lead to fewer bugs than the procedural approach:

```
test[t_, dt_] := {#, MemberQ[{0.01, 0.02}, #]} & /@ Range[dt, t, dt];
```

Which when run,

```
test[0.01, 0.001] // TableForm
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Replacing `TableForm` with `InputForm` reveals that one does not totally avoid floating-point error...

Comment: @J.M. that's interesting, it makes me curious as to why that happens, the increment doesn't seem to be anywhere near the limit of precision of of a floating point number. Is this a general effect with FP numbers or more specific to MMA?

Comment: it's general, see e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @acl, Thanks, surprising how in a great number of years that's never knowingly tripped me up, but here because `MemberQ` is being used as a criterion, rather than a < or > based test, it become obvious.