# Why I'm getting 9999s after decimal and how do I fix it?

Tags: arithmetic

Check the screen shot. Why I'm getting 999s? It is suppose to be 127,977.52

[image]

Thanks in advance,

---

Quick solution:  AccountingForm[58156.48 + 69821.04, 16]

And thanks to Yves Klett

Comment: Welcome! The bugs tag is for confirmed bugs only.

Comment: Not to worry. What you are seeing is not a bug but a result of machine precision arithmetic. This is actually a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5580/131. Also useful: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: There are only two digits after decimal in the input, so ideally it output only 2 digits for additions or subtractions. Is there a way to get output like 127,977.52 in the above case?

Comment: Thanks checking those links, when I posted didn't saw those links.

Comment: The only way to "fix" this would be to use [exact numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18485/131). Most of the time this will not be neccessary however.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) For quick solution this one works for me AccountingForm[58156.48 + 69821.04, 16]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem for anything that uses machine precision floats, e.g. Mathematica, Matlab, C, etc.

Consider the simpler example $1/10$. In base 10, this fraction has the finite decimal expansion $$ 1/10 = 0.1 $$
But your machine would store this number (and all floats) in binary. The problem is, in binary $1/10$ has the infinite decimal expansion
$$ 1/10 = \left(0.000\overline{1100}\right)_2 $$
This means your machine must to round (since it can't store infinite digits). This introduces error.

Now for your problem, we can see your decimals don't have a finite expansion in binary using `RealDigits`:

```
RealDigits[58156.48, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
>   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 16}
> ```

```
RealDigits[69821.04, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 17}
> ```

As Yves said in the comments, a fix in Mathematica is to avoid machine precision and use exact precision. Here I am forcing both numbers to have the first 20 digits correct:

```
58156.48`20 + 69821.04`20 // InputForm
```

> ```
> 127977.52`20.
> ```

Comment: Thanks
58156.48`20 + 69821.04`20 // InputForm
That is exactly what I was looking for.