# Why does this whole number have a recurring value?

Tags: numerics, arithmetic

I have a math question which that may seem simple to some but not to me if you where to do the calculation 12.30 * 12 it would equal 147.60 but why is that when I show the answer to more then two decimal place it has a 2 at the end 147.60000000000002 where did the 2 come from if 12.30 is a whole number ?

Again Im sorry if this sounds dumb but Im curious and thought this is the best place to ask.

Comment: It looks like it is an artifact of how numbers are represented in binary internally.

Comment: `Rationalize[12.30]*12`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a numerical artifact that is due to finite precision of computer calculations. Indeed, when one computes

```
SetAccuracy[12.30*12, 15]
```

> 147.60000000000002

It's notable that the input is in decimal system (at least the user thinks of it as such), but the computer uses its binary representation. For example, $\frac{1}{10}$ is an exact number, but 0.1 has an infinite expansion when expressed in binary (i.e., $0.1_{10}=0.000110011001100110011001100110011..._2$; see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66482/22013)). Hence the computer never uses exactly $\frac{1}{10}$ but a rounded number:

```
SetAccuracy[0.1, 20]
```

> 0.1000000000000000056

What you see above in the case of `12.30*12` is most likely a result of such *rounding*. It should be also noted that in most published materials, when some result is given to e.g. 20 decimal digits, in most cases it is not reasonable: in fact, every machine will give a slightly different output. The computation on two different computers (or different software) can give results different on the 15th or 12th or some other decimal place.

Comment: Thank you for this makes a lot of sense