# 'Det' precision

Tags: numerics

Am I missing basic logic ?

We all know Determinant of both these matrices are 0.

But when executed on my system (Windows10 64bit) 
[image: mathematica on system]

The same when executed in Online Mathematica
[image: online mathematica]

I was trying to use a conditional statement based on `Det` ,
am I left with `Det[...]<(10^-7)` type of condition instead of checking equality?

Comment: Related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: [See why](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125694/22013). Solution: `Chop@Det[{{-1, -2.5}, {-2.5, -6.25}}] == 0` yields `True`.

Comment: How could online mathematica return it right ? ... So I may not use chop whenever I deal with floating numbers right ... How can I make sure this doesn't spoil my work ( It took a lot of time to find this as I was unaware of such thing )

Comment: It is curious as to why the Wolfram Cloud returns `0.`.  `exp := Det[{{-1, -2.5}, {-2.5, -6.25}}]`, then `{CloudEvaluate[exp], exp}`.  Difference in OS maybe?

Comment: It is a difference between Linux and Windows at least.

Comment: I get `Det[{{-1., -2.5}, {-2.5, -6.25}}] == 0. (*True*)` on win7/64 bit, which it seems we should actually expect since the numbers in this example are exactly representable in binary.  Of course you cant count on it, `Det[{{-1., -2.9}, {-2.9, -8.41}}]` is not exactly zero for example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result on V11 (Mac 10.11.6): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba4Ad.png -- Perhaps the online Mathematica is using V11 (maybe on a Mac).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a well known problem of [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) that equality comparisons are unreliable.  For example if you try

```
1.0 == 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.1
```

in Python or C or any other traditional language, you get false.  Why?  Because these numbers are not exactly representable in binary the same way as $1/3 = 0.33333333\dots$ is not exactly representable in decimal using a finite number of digits.  Due to this, and potentially due to numerical roundoff errors the two sides won't be digit-for-digit equal up to the last binary digit.

You are probably aware of this.

Now try in *Mathematica*:

```
In[151]:= 1.0 == 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.1
Out[151]= True
```

Mathematica tries to be helpful and equality comparisons have some tolerance.  [This can be controlled by `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748/695132), which is set to 7 binary digits by default.

```
Internal`$EqualTolerance
(* 2.10721 *)

Log[2, 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance]
(* 7. *)
```

This choice of 7 digits is of course rather arbitrary and even though equality comparisons behave in a nice and convenient way most of the time, you must keep in mind that they are not foolproof, and cannot be foolproof even in principle.

The difficulty is that your determinant is zero:

```
Det@N[{{-1, -5/2}, {-5/2, -25/4}}]
(* 3.46945*10^-16 *)
```

When saying "equal except for the last 7 binary digits" (or $\sim 2.1$ decimal digits), we are talking about a *relative* tolerance.  Relative tolerances don't really work for zero values because we can't divide by zero.  Or rather: since floating point numbers are stored as a separate exponent and mantissa, once the result is zero, the last few normally insignificant mantissa digits are shifted up into positions which *appear* significant.

People have already pointed out [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), which deals exactly with this problem.  It converts floating point numbers smaller than a certain threshold ($10^{-10}$ by default) into exact `0`.  I.e. it uses an absolute tolerance, not a relative one.

Another way to deal with it is to use Mathematica's arbitrary precision [inexact](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) numbers instead of [machine precision numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html).  The former have built-in precision tracking, so the system can detect that a zero that arises due to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) has very few accurate digits.  This is also not foolproof, but it's much better than no precision tracking at all.  Arbitrary precision numbers can be forced by [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) or by using [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) *with a second argument* on exact numbers.  Observe:

```
Det[{{a, b}, {b, d}}]
(* -b^2 + a d *)

% /. N[{a -> -1, b -> -5/2, d -> -25/4}, 10]
(* 0.*10^-9 *)

Accuracy[%]
(* 8.60206 *)

%% == 0
(* True *)
```

The result is zero, but it has lost some accuracy.  The zero comparison evaluates to `True`.

Unfortunately, when using `Det` directly on such an arbitrary precision matrix, it doesn't perform the precision tracking:

```
Det@N[{{-1, -5/2}, {-5/2, -25/4}}, 10]
(* -1.469367939*10^-38 *)

{Accuracy[%], Precision[%]}
(* {47.8329, 10.} *)
```

Note that we have both [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) and [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) in Mathematica.  [The former is a relative measure, the latter an absolute one.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)  Since `Precision` is a relative measure, it is less meaningful with a zero result.

Comment: It's curious that others seem to get nonzero results, but I get `0.` for `Det@N[{{-1, -5/2}, {-5/2, -25/4}}]` on both V10.4.1 and V11.0.0.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get `0.` too in v. 10.0