# Mod is behaving funny

Tags: numerics

I have a silly question.

```
k = 0.15;
kf = 0.03;
Mod[k, kf]
```

is giving me `0` as it should but when I change `kf` to `0.05` like

```
k = 0.15;
kf = 0.05;
Mod[k, kf]
```

it is giving me `0.05` when it should also be zero.

In short: while does Mathematica think that `Mod[0.15, 0.05] = 0.05`?

Comment: Machine numbers in a computer are not the same as decimal numbers for pen and paper. Here you need exact numbers, so use k=15/100, kf=3/100, 5/100. The answer to your question is: numerical noise.

Comment: Also [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125694/22013).

Comment: Thank you Fred, that helps though it is still unclear why it does it correctly in one case and incorrectly in another