# the result of Mod is surprising!

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I am using *Mathematica* 11.1.1 and I was surprised when I saw:

```
Mod[0.2, 0.2] == 0.
Mod[0.4, 0.2] == 0.
Mod[0.6, 0.2] == 0.2
Mod[1.0, 0.2] == 0.2
```

I cannot understand why the last two results are wrong!!

Comment: Mod 0.2, they are correct, since `Mod[0.,0.2]` equals `Mod[0.2,0.2]`... However, this is weird, indeed.

Comment: This is not surprising at all; see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125693/why-does-this-whole-number-have-a-recurring-value), and evaluate `Mod[6/10,2/10]`.

Comment: @corey979 Doh. Right...