# Inexact numbers as keys in Association?

Tags: associations, machine-precision

Can someone explain me how Mathematica's Associations behave with inexact numbers as keys:

```
<| 0.22499999999999964` -> a |> [0.22499999999999965`]
```

and

```
<| 0.22499999999999964` -> a |> [0.22499999999999961`]
```

both give the value a, whereas

```
 <| 0.22499999999999964` -> a |> [0.22499999999999966`] gives Missing as an answer.
```

Comment: Looks like [this thing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5580), but with associations. Why do you need to use inexact numbers as keys?

Comment: "Can someone explain me how Mathematica's Associations behave [...]?" They behave badly. Don't do that.

Comment: `Association` is the name of the function in *Mathematica*, so I am not sure what was productive about the edit I just rolled back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lookups with inexact numbers behave like other lookups: they use hashing. We can check that the results are consistent with what `Hash` does.

```
vals = {0.22499999999999961`, 0.22499999999999964`, 
   0.22499999999999965`, 0.22499999999999966`};
Hash /@ vals

(* Out[11]= {1879126079618645156, 1879126079618645156, \
1879126079618645156, 5861724109654749116} *)
```

When hashing approximate values, there are going to be sharp boundaries (discontinuities, in effect). This is a tradeoff between having "very" close neighbors hash to the same value, and maintaining transitivity.